# how do you get current day's starting time and the most current time in milliseconds

Tags: javascript

Need to get the curent time and 00:00 in the morning in milliseconds? I need to do this automatically every day, current starting morning (00:00:00) and current time in milliseconds? Has anyone done something like this?

Comment: In milliseconds relative to what?

Comment: The JavaScript [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object API has all you need.

Comment: @rink.attendant.6, I need it in terms of milliseconds starting 1970

Comment: Date.now() will give the current time in ms since epoch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works :

```
function millisecondDiff(myDate) {
  var midnightDay = myDate.getUTCDate();
  var midnightMonth = myDate.getUTCMonth() + 1;
  var midnightYear = myDate.getUTCFullYear();
  var midnightMilliseconds = new Date(midnightYear + '/' + midnightMonth + '/' + midnightDay).getTime();
  return new Date().getTime() - midnightMilliseconds;
}

var millisSinceMidnight = millisecondDiff(new Date());
console.log(millisSinceMidnight + ' ms');
console.log((millisSinceMidnight / 1000) + ' s');
console.log((millisSinceMidnight / (1000 * 60)) + ' min');
console.log((millisSinceMidnight / (1000 * 60 * 60)) + ' h');
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the current time in milliseconds since epoch (any of these work):

```
Date.now()
new Date().valueOf()
new Date().getTime()
```

To get 00:00:00

```
var d = new Date();
d.setHours(0);
d.setMinutes(0);
d.setSeconds(0);
d.setMilliseconds(0)
d.valueOf(); // or d.getTime()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Current time
var date = Date.now();

// Since this morning
var date2 = new Date();
date2.setHours(0);
date2.setMinutes(0);
date2.setSeconds(0);
date2.setMilliseconds(0);
```

See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LNZxY/)